# Is it possible to restore SSH key?

Tags: ssh

I have reinstalled OS, but didn't backup SSH keys, only bitbucket has the exported key for now:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc.... mymail@gmail.com
```

Is it possible to restore my key using this exported one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you upload to BitBucket is only the [public half of the key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). It is not practically possible to recover the private half from it.